# Python: Why are eigenvectors not the same as first PCA weights?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pca, eigenvector

Let's generate an array:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(30).reshape(10,3)
data=data*data
array([[  0,   1,   4],
       [  9,  16,  25],
       [ 36,  49,  64],
       [ 81, 100, 121],
       [144, 169, 196],
       [225, 256, 289],
       [324, 361, 400],
       [441, 484, 529],
       [576, 625, 676],
       [729, 784, 841]])
```

Then find the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix:

```
mn = np.mean(data, axis=0)
data -= mn
C = np.cov(data.T)
evals, evecs = la.eig(C)
idx = np.argsort(evals)[::-1]
evecs = evecs[:,idx]
print evecs
array([[-0.53926461, -0.73656433,  0.40824829],
       [-0.5765472 , -0.03044111, -0.81649658],
       [-0.61382979,  0.67568211,  0.40824829]])
```

Now let's run the matplotlib.mlab.PCA function on the data:

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
mpca=mlab.PCA(data)
print mpca.Wt
[[ 0.57731894  0.57740574  0.57732612]
 [ 0.72184459 -0.03044628 -0.69138514]
 [ 0.38163232 -0.81588947  0.43437443]]
```

Why are the two matrices different?  I thought that in finding the PCA, first one had to find the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, and that this would be exactly equal to the weights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to normalize your data, not just center it, and the output of `np.linalg.eig` has to be transposed to match that of `mlab.PCA`:

```
>>> n_data = (data - data.mean(axis=0)) / data.std(axis=0)
>>> evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(n_data.T))
>>> evecs = evecs[:, np.argsort(evals)[::-1]].T
>>> mlab.PCA(data).Wt
array([[ 0.57731905,  0.57740556,  0.5773262 ],
       [ 0.72182079, -0.03039546, -0.69141222],
       [ 0.38167716, -0.8158915 ,  0.43433121]])
>>> evecs
array([[-0.57731905, -0.57740556, -0.5773262 ],
       [-0.72182079,  0.03039546,  0.69141222],
       [ 0.38167716, -0.8158915 ,  0.43433121]])
```

Comment: Eigenvectors here appear along the rows of the matrices, correct ?

Comment: Yes, the return of `np.linalg.eig` has eigenvectors as columns, so after transposition they are in rows.

Comment: What is c_data in the first line, please?

Comment: My bad, it should be `data`, corrected it. It was the original data centered but not normalized.